# Create a 2 dimensional array according to an existing array

Tags: python, arrays

I have a array as [2, 3, 1, 3, 1]
I want to define a 2 dimensional array of all 0s according to [2, 3, 1, 3, 1]
it will be something like

```
[ [0,0], [0,0,0], [0], [0,0,0], [0] ]
```

how to do it without hardcoding?

Answer (score 2):

you could do something like this :

```
[[0 for x in range(y)] for y in [2,3,1,3,1]]
```

Comment: While it is not clear form the invalid output, the OP does ask for a 2-dimensional array, not a 3-dimensional one.

Comment: This is pretty hard to see with his data structure : ```[ [0][0], [0][0][0], [0], [0][0][0], [0] ]``` I was thinking that meant : ```[[[0], [0]], [[0], [0], [0]], [[0]], [[0], [0], [0]], [[0]]]```. I made the changes thanks

Answer (score 2):

A simple comprehension will do:

```
array = [2, 3, 1, 3, 1]

zeroes = [[0] * x for x in array]
# [[0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0], [0, 0, 0], [0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:-

```
c = [2, 3, 1, 3, 1]
RA = []
for v in c:
    RA.append([0 for _ in range(v)])
print(RA)
```

There's probably a more compact way of doing this but this should make it clear what you need to do